# LATEX Table Does not Align

Tags: tables, xetex

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\titleformat{\section}         
  {\scshape\raggedright} 
   \usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}

\section*{TEST}
\begin{tabular}{!{\hskip .0in}L!{\hskip .55in}R}
2000 & Text\\
2004$-$2005 & More Text Here\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\section*{Section 1}
\begin{tabular}{>{}l<{} !{\hspace{0.1in}} l}
Year$-$Now & Data 1\\
& Data 2 may be different in length and may be much longer in fact\\
Year$-$Now & Data 3 may vary in length\\
& Data 4 even if it is longer\\
\end{tabular}


\section*{Section 2}
\begin{tabular}{>{}l<{} !{\hspace{0.1in}} l}
Year & {This text is much longer}\\
 & this text is also greater in length as you can see\\
\\
Year & {More information here}\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Where are defined `L` and `R`?

Comment: left and right i believe

Comment: Well, `L` and `R` had to be defined somewhere, they are not default column specifiers. See if the following gives, what you looking for: `\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\section*{TEST}

\begin{tabular}{>{$}l<{$} !{\hspace{0.55in}} r}
2000            & Text\\
2004-2005   & More Text Here\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}`.

Comment: @Zarko that is perfect, I do have a quesiton. If I have something like 2004-Current instead of 2004-2005 it makes 'Current' italics. How I can turn that off. And thank you this is so great

Comment: @Zarko here is definition for L and R \newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedleft}p{0.05\textwidth}}
\newcolumntype{R}{p{0.8\textwidth}}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you looking for one from the following examples:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}

\section*{TEST}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{>{$}l<{$} !{\hspace{0.55in}} >{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}
2000        & Text\\
2004-2005   & More Text Here\\
\end{tabularx}

\medskip
or 
\medskip

\noindent%
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} >{$}l<{$} !{\hspace{0.55in}} >{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X @{}}
2000        & Text\\
2004-2005   & More Text Here\\
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, instead of `tabular` and your definitions for `L` and `R` is used `\tabularx` table and `X` column type. Since the width of `tabularx` is prescribed to be text width, table width is from left text border to right text border.

**Addendum:** with editing your question you actually ask new question ... anyway, as solution for it can be the following (I guess):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X}

\begin{document}

\section*{Section 1}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{p{5em} !{\hspace{0.1in}} L}
Year -- Now & Data 1\\
            & Data 2 may be different in length and may be much longer in fact\\
    \addlinespace
Year -- Now & Data 3 may vary in length \\
            & Data 4 are very long, so and they may be longer than column width. Consequently in such a case they will be broken into two or more lines\\
   \addlinespace
Year -- Now & Data 5 may vary in length \\
            & Data 4 even if it is longer and it may be broken into many lines\\
\end{tabularx}


\section*{Section 2}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{p{5em} !{\hspace{0.1in}} L}
Year        & This text is much longer  \\      
            & Text in the second row is very long, consequently it is broken into many lines\\
    \addlinespace
2020 -- 2020    & More information here\\
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: please see updated question

Comment: @bvowe, this actually is new question. It is also not clear, what is now your problem. Constant width of the first column? Left aligning text in the second column?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
\begin{tabular}{l p{3em} r}
    2000 && Text\\
    2004$-$2005 && More Text Here\\
\end{tabular}
```

Just tweak spacing value after `p` in brackets to achieve desired results.

[image]
[image]